# How to extract the Windows OEM Key from Windows

Tags: c++, windows

How would I go about extracting the Windows OEM Key from the Registry and saving it to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're well into unsupported territory here. The product key is stored in encrypted form in the registry. You might want to look at [Magical Jellybean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)'s code, which is available under the GPL.